# Web fonts mime type warning

Tags: embedded-fonts, webfonts, mime-message

I'm using the free web fonts service via webfonts.fonts.com which are being served by their server and i'm getting the following warning in my Chrome/Safari browser console: **"Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream."**

This is the JS link fonts.com specify to place in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/f3d92ff3-2575-4cb8-a4b8-9b4c5d0376fb.js"></script>
```

This is the CSS i'm using:

```
h1 { margin-bottom: 10px;font: 35px/35px 'Helvetica W01 Blk', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #00AEEF; }
```

I don't know what the warning means and wondered since it's only a warning and not an error, whether it's that critical.
I've tested the site on various browsers, Mac and PC and on the face of it everything worked and looked as it should.

Can anyone shed any light as to whether i'm doing something wrong or even if this is an issue or not?
Gladly post any more information in necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning is perfectly safe to ignore. Our service uses the "application/octet-stream" as a generic MIME type for our font data because there do not seem to be any officially standardized/recognized MIME types for the various web font formats. There are indeed some suggestions by various entities for some of the formats, however, using this generic MIME type helps us maximize compatibility with our supported browsers.

If you do have any trouble with the service functioning correctly, please don't hesitate to contact us by sending a ticket from our support form:

http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/ContactUs/TechnicalSupport

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation :) I wasn't sure if I was doing something or not.

Comment: Would be great if there was a way to suppress these errors? They clutter up the console and make it more difficult to debug other errors

Comment: Check out this [link for solution](http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/resource-interpreted-font-transferred-mime-type): 

You can remove these warnings in your console by updating the configuration for your web server with the following MIME type per font file extension:

.ttf — font/truetype
.otf — font/opentype
.eot — application/vnd.ms-fontobject
.woff — application/x-font-woff
. 
 

If using Apache config, use AddType directive for each font type in .htaccess:

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/opentype otf
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff